# cassandra 3.7 ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses (including data)

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 3.7 version with 5 nodes running in cluster.

I observed follwing messages in cassandra logs.

> DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2018-07-04 22:51:53,623
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses (only
>   digests) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2018-07-05 06:46:14,031
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2018-07-05 06:46:14,185
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-3] 2018-07-05 06:46:14,534
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-5] 2018-07-05 06:46:14,819
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses (only
>   digests) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-7] 2018-07-05 06:46:17,785
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-3] 2018-07-06 13:04:34,090
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-4] 2018-07-06 13:04:34,422
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses (only
>   digests) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2018-07-06 13:04:34,551
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-5] 2018-07-06 13:04:35,369
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses (only
>   digests) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2018-07-07 02:50:06,216
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2018-07-07 02:50:07,940
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data)

When I checked cluster through nodetool netstats it shows no problem

```
 nodetool  netstats
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 184532
Mismatch (Blocking): 6560
Mismatch (Background): 1686
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Dropped
Large messages                  n/a         0          11196         0
Small messages                  n/a         0       47687862         0
Gossip messages                 n/a         0        2011406         0
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what RF is your data and what CL are you using?

Comment: Hi Chris,
I am unable to understand what is expected,can you please expalin in details
What do you mean by RF ? and CL?

Comment: In my opinion, issue is more generic. 
I was trying to correlate it with Gossip Failure Detection mechanism, but I’m not sure if that’s true. 
I have attached logs from one of Cassandra nodes where you can see that Cassandra constantly reports about issues with Gossip Failure Detection protocol as well
as errors about inability to complete queries execution because of Timed Out response from some of Cassandra nodes, that are probably were temporarily marked as Down (not sure). Again, I cannot say that this is related, but here’s what I see based on historical logs:

Comment: replication factor of the keyspace and consistency level used on query

Comment: This is status for replication factor:-                       keyspace_name                       | durable_writes | replication

                  system_distributed |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}
                              system |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
             db1 |           True |  {'ap-south': '3', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy','replication_factor': '3'}

Comment: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.7 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> CONSISTENCY;
Current consistency level is ONE.